# undefined variable in modal

Tags: php, html, mysql

if i click on view button in my table it should open an modal form and 
       display all table values to view it.But i'm getting error as undefined 
       variable in the textbox inside of location,where i called only location 
       in the table.kindly help out me with how to get datas from dbs as php 
       code.thanks in advance.
**UPDATE: I had updated my code.Kindly check it out,as i called ajax ,but modal box open with empty ,no informations loaded.kindly help it out.**

```html
<!-- Main content -->
 <div class="main-content">
  <h1 class="page-title">OUR POP DETAILS</h1>
  <!-- Breadcrumb -->
  <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-2"> 
   <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="basic-tables.html">Metro Pop</a></li> 
   <li class="active"><strong>Action</strong></li> 
  </ol>
  
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"></div>
     
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php $apage = array('id'=>'','name'=>'');?>
        <script>var page_0 = <?php echo json_encode($apage)?></script>
        <h3><a data="page_0" class="model_form btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add new record</a></h3>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="table-container">
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="col-md-12">
           <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-sortable table-condensed  " cellspacing="0" width="100%"
     
     
                           data-show-columns="true"
                           >
                        
     
     
     
     
     
     
     

 
     
            <tbody>
   
                <?php if(isset($result) && ($data_record) > 0)  : $i=1; ?>
                    <?php  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>
     

                        <tr class="<?=$users->id?>_del">
      
                            <td><?=$i;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->zonee;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->location;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->pop_type;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->switch_name;?></td>
         <td><?=$users->switch_ip;?></td>
         <td><?=$users->switch_make;?></td>
         <td><?=$users->switch_serial;?></td>
         <td><?=$users->switch_model;?></td>
                           
                            <td> <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?=$users->latitude;?>,<?=$users->longitude;?>" target=\"_blank\"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a></td>
       
                            <script>var page_<?php echo $users->id ?> = <?php echo json_encode($users);?></script>
       
                            <td><a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
       
                            <a data="<?php echo  $users->id ?>" title="Delete <?php echo $users->name;?>" class="tip delete_check btn btn-info btn-sm "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>  
     
         
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal"  data-id="<?php echo $users->id; ?>"  class=" view_check  btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
       </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php $i++; 
    } ?>
            <?php else : echo '<tr><td colspan="8"><div align="center">-------No record found -----</div></td></tr>'; ?>
           <?php endif; ?>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
          <?php
              if(isset($_SESSION['flash_msg'])) :  
               $message = $_SESSION['flash_msg'];
               echo $error= '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> <strong>'.$message.'</strong> </div>';
               unset($_SESSION['flash_msg']);
              endif;
          ?>


         

         
</div>
      </div>
     
  </div> 
  
    
    
    
     
<div id="view-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-dialog"> 
      <div class="modal-content"> 
                  
         <div class="modal-header"> 
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> 
             <h4 class="modal-title">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> POP Information
             </h4> 
         </div> 
        
         <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail"> 
                                       
            
                             
         </div> 
  
           
       <div class="modal-footer"> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
       </div>  
              
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>











<!-- Form modal -->
  <div id="form_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify2"></i><span id="pop_title">ADD</span> POP INFORMATION</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Form inside modal -->
        <form method="post" action="add_edit.php" id="cat_form">
          <div class="modal-body with-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
     
     
     
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>zonee :</label>
                   <input type="text" name="zonee" id="zonee"  class="form-control required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>location :</label>
                   <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="form-control required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>pop_type :</label>
                   <input type="text" name="pop_type" id="pop_type" class="form-control required number">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="switch_name" id="switch_name" class="form-control required number">
                   
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_ip :</label>
                   <input type="text"  name="switch_ip" id="switch_ip" class="form-control required" >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_make :</label>
        <input type="text"  name="switch_make" id="switch_make" class="form-control required" >
                   
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_serial :</label>
      <input type="text"  name="switch_serial" id="switch_serial" class="form-control required" >
                   
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
   <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_model :</label>
       <input type="text"  name="switch_model" id="switch_model" class="form-control required" >
                 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>Latitude:</label>
       <input type="text"  name="latitude" id="latitude" class="form-control required" >
                 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>Longitude:</label>
       <input type="text"  name="longitude" id="longitude" class="form-control required" >
                 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
   
   
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <span id="add">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id">
              <button type="submit" name="form_data" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- /form modal -->
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.model_form',function(){
        $('#form_modal').modal({
          keyboard: false,
          show:true,
          backdrop:'static'
        });
        var data = eval($(this).attr('data'));
        $('#id').val(data.id);
    $('#zonee').val(data.zonee);
        $('#location').val(data.location);
        $('#pop_type').val(data.pop_type);
        $('#switch_name').val(data.switch_name);
        $('#switch_ip').val(data.switch_ip);
        $('#switch_make').val(data.switch_make);
        $('#switch_serial').val(data.switch_serial);
   $('#switch_model').val(data.switch_model);
   $('#latitude').val(data.latitude);
   $('#longitude').val(data.longitude);
        if(data.id!="")
            $('#pop_title').html('Edit');
  
        else 
            $('#pop_title').html('Add');
   
       
    });  
    $(document).on('click','.delete_check',function(){
      if(confirm("Are you sure to delete data")){
        var current_element = $(this);
        url = "add_edit.php";
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        data: {ct_id:$(current_element).attr('data')},
        success: function(data) { //location.reload(); 
          $('.'+$(current_element).attr('data')+'_del').animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        } 
      });
      }
     });     
  
  
  
  $(document).on('click', '.view_check', function(){
  //$('#dataModal').modal();
  var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
   url:"view.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{employee_id:employee_id},
   success:function(data){
    $('#employee_detail').html(data);
    $('#view-modal').modal('show');
   }
  });
 });
});  
  
  
  
});
</script>
```

```html
**view.php**

<?php  
 
    include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST["employee_id"]))
{
 $output = '';
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mine");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
     $output .= '
     <tr>  
            <td width="30%"><label>Name</label></td>  
            <td width="70%">'.$users["location"].'</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td width="30%"><label>Address</label></td>  
            <td width="70%">'.$users["zonee"].'</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td width="30%"><label>Gender</label></td>  
            <td width="70%">'.$users["pop_type"].'</td>  
        </tr>
        
        
     ';
    }
    $output .= '</table></div>';
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: do you get error only in location ?

Comment: yes.

Use of undefined constant location - assumed 'location' in on line : 334
Undefined variable: row in line 334

Comment: what you take as a $row ? can you show a query ?

Comment: i have used $users , it shows only textbox,but not fetched location from database. i need,label as location, and in textbox i need to get that location value

Comment: if you have $users so why you write $row ?

Comment: I have changed now $row to $users ,mistakenly written

Comment: still in modal you used $row.and if you change $users still that cant work because you closed while loop before modal. you need to use ajax call

Comment: now i have changed to 

 <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label>location :</label>
          <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php 
          echo $users['location'];?>" />

        </div>

Comment: how to use ajax call here?

Comment: you just want to show data from database in modal on click. right ?

Comment: yes. that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Add quota('') like $row['location'] , you are using $row[location]

Or use below code

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
          <label>location :</label>
          <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php 
          echo $row['location'];?>" />

        </div>
```

Comment: you know what is $row ?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name is `$users` not `$row` so you can write this

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <label>location :</label>
          <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php 
          echo $users['location'];?>" />

        </div>
```

Comment: thats ok. i have userd $users ,but it didn't fetch value from database,it shows only textbox,but not fetched location from database. i need,label as location, and in textbox i need to get that location value.

Comment: You are using 'mysqli_fetch_object'  this is OOP style so you can show your location like echo $users->location. Change this echo $users['location'] to echo $users->location. This may solve your problem

Comment: by changing that also not solved my problem.
Gives error
Trying to get property of non-object in <b> on line 334

Comment: <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" id="getUser" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
        is this is correct ??

Comment: no that is not correct for your code as you use mysqli_fetch_object so write this  $users->user_id instead of $row['user_id']

Comment: even if i changed ,i am getting a text box with location: [textbox with error like trying to get property of non-object]

Comment: Then move this code in While loop not outside   <div class="modal-body"> 

         <div id="dynamic-content"> <!-- mysql data will load in table -->
         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <label>location :</label>
              <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php 
              echo $row[location];?>" />

            </div>




          </div>
        </div>


         </div> 

     </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
   <tbody>

        <?php if(isset($result) && ($data_record) > 0)  : $i=1; ?>
            <?php  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>


                <tr class="<?=$users->id?>_del">

                    <td><?=$i;?></td>
                    <td><?=$users->zonee;?></td>
                    <td><?=$users->location;?></td>
                    <td><?=$users->pop_type;?></td>
                    <td><?=$users->switch_name;?></td>
                      <td><?=$users->switch_ip;?></td>
                      <td><?=$users->switch_make;?></td>
                      <td><?=$users->switch_serial;?></td>
                      <td><?=$users->switch_model;?></td>

                    <td> <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?=$users-
           >latitude;?>,<?=$users->longitude;?>" target=\"_blank\"><i 
        class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a></td>

                    <script>var page_<?php echo $users->id ?> = <?php 
       echo json_encode($users);?></script>

                    <td><a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" 
     class="model_form btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#"> <span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>

                    <a data="<?php echo  $users->id ?>" title="Delete <?
         php echo $users->name;?>" class="tip delete_check btn btn-info 
   btn-sm "><span 
         class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>  

                     <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-
            modal" data-id="<?php echo $users->id; ?>" id="getUser" 
                   class="btn btn-sm 
               btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
                </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php $i++; 
        echo "<div class='modal-body'> 

     <div id='dynamic-content'> 
     <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
          <label>location :</label>
          <input type='text' name='location' id='location' value='$users->location' />

        </div>




      </div>
    </div>


     </div> 

 </div> "
    } ?>
    <?php else : echo '<tr><td colspan="8"><div align="center">-------No 
      record found -----</div></td></tr>'; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>               
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

On Click Call Function

```
<script>
      function launch_modal(id)
      {
        //Store id in variable
        var newId = id;
        //Ajax Start
         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "your_php_page.php",
          //send id to php page
          data: {theId:newId},
          success: function(data){
            //to display data in paragraph of Modal
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
            //to display modal
            $('#myModal').modal("show");
          },
        });
      }
</script>
```

your_php_page.php

```
<?php
    $theId = $_POST['theId'];
    if($theId){

        $output = '';
        $sql = $conn->query("select * from table where id = '$theId'");
        $fetch = $sql->fetch_object();
        //Append
        $output .= '<table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name :</td>
                        <td>'.$fetch->name.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number :</td>
                        <td>'.$fetch->number.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
        echo $output;
    }
?>
```

Comment: i need to write onclick function on view button right?

And in modal -body did i need to use, <label>location :</label>
          <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php 
          echo $row['location'];?>" />

Comment: yes,on click call ajax function.the result return by php page is written  to modal body.so for that give specific id to modal-body or class name as i answered.if it might helpful please give upvote

Comment: <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" id="getUser"  class=" view_check btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
       Is this is correct?

Comment: that's correct but try it you'll find some silly errors read carfuly and solve it.